# Remove character from string at specific location

Tags: bash, tr

This seems too easy but still can't get it work. I have:

```
-X-1.5
```

and need:

```
-X1.5
```

Using:

```
echo -X-1.5 | tr -d '-'
```

gives:

```
X1.5
```

which it's close, but not close enough.

Any pointers are welcome,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another sed solution

```
echo "-X-1.5" | sed 's/-//2'
```

Substitute the second occurrence of - with nothing.

Answer (score 5):

If you know that the character to delete is at position 2 (starting counting from 0), you can do this:

```
VAR="-X-1.5"
echo "${VAR:0:2}${VAR:3}"
```

which will give `-X1.5`.

If it were the first instance of a character that you wanted to delete, but you didn't know its position in advance, you could do this:

```
VAR="X-1.5-oh"
echo "${VAR/-/}"
```

which will give `X1.5-oh`.

Comment: OP seems to have meant 'occurrence' instead of 'location' and accepted as correct an answer that found a specific occurrence of a character in a string. This is a better answer if location is meant as 'specific character position with in the string'

Answer (score 1):

Since the part to remove happens not to be at the beginning, end, nor is this a complete removal, it rules out a lot of generic shortcuts in favor of something more specific to match a known pattern, so it really depends on what the pattern will be..

If for example the pattern is always going to be a `-X` followed by `-` which you wish to remove, you can, for example:

```
$ echo "-X-1.5" | sed 's/-X-/-X/g'
```

Results:

```
-X1.5
```

- searches for `-X-`
- replaces with `-X`
- `/g` to perform it greedily meaning all such occurrences, in case you have `-X-1.5-X-2.5-X-3.5` etc